# Kodak Kiosk Facebook implementation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, kiosk

If you watch the video below, Kodak has implemented Facebook integration into their kiosks so you can print your Facebook photos.

http://www.kodak.com/global/en/consumer/kiosk/pff/printFromFacebook.jhtml?pq-path=164/7959/2301161

My question is how did they implement the authorization without using the authorization dialogs?  They just take in a username and password and list out photos.  I can't find any documentation on authorizing this way, which makes me think this is some special implementation.  Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are correct that this is a special implementation. From the [Facebook API Terms of Service](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/):

> You must not include functionality that proxies, requests or collects Facebook usernames or passwords.

FIOS does something similar too, which leads me to believe that there is another (not necessarily public) way to auth this way.